# Populate a field on changeform_view

Tags: django-admin

When I open an item in a model, for example: `/shop_push/shopapidefinition/4/change/` I want to populate one field with my own value and leave the rest intact.

I can currently do something when I edit, like below

```
class ShopApiDefinitionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # let's define this so there's no chance of AttributeErrors
        self._request = None
        super(ShopApiDefinitionAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_request(self):
        return self._request

    def changeform_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # stash the request
        self._request = request
        print "changelist_view ShopApiDefinitionAdmin"

        # call the parent view method with all the original args
        # ShopApiDefinitionAdmin['about_the_shop'] = "hello"
        return super(ShopApiDefinitionAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What I don't know how to do it add data to a field for that record, for example

`field['about_the_shop'] = "new text"`

It would be nice to save the new data, but that isn't essential.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realised that it was probably best to use `change_view` and that this triggers before the content is retrieved from the model, so what I do is used the `object_id`, query the record, do my code and then save the details

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    # Get the record
    obj = ShopApiDefinition.objects.get(id=object_id)
    # get a value as I use that in my code
    self.password = obj.password
    # do some code
    shopify_shop = "a value from my code"
    obj.about_the_shop = shopify_shop  # change field
    obj.save()  # this will update only

    return super(ShopApiDefinitionAdmin, self).change_view(
        request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
    )
```

That seems to work.  It saved the value in the model, and when the form loads it is populated with both the existing data and then new data from my code

Thanks

Grant